# graphql-compose-mongoose generating an error: Expected [object Object] to be a GraphQL schema

Tags: graphql-js

I'm new to graphql-compose

I'm trying to launch a first service on a simple mongoose schema:

graphql.js :

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { composeWithMongoose} from 'graphql-compose-mongoose'
import { schemaComposer } from 'graphql-compose'

const db = require( '../models/db' )
//const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const folderDAO = mongoose.model('folder');

const customizationOptions = {}; // left it empty for simplicity, described below
const folderTC = composeWithMongoose(folderDAO, customizationOptions);

schemaComposer.rootQuery().addFields({
    folderOne: folderTC.getResolver('findOne'),
})

const graphqlSchema = schemaComposer.buildSchema()

console.log("Schema built : ", graphqlSchema )

export default graphqlSchema
```

Now in my server code, I have this:

```
const express = require('express');
const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql')
const GraphQLSchema = require('./app_api/routes/graphql')
    app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
        schema: GraphQLSchema,
        graphiql: true,
        formatError: error => ({
            message: error.message,
            locations: error.locations,
            stack: error.stack ? error.stack.split('\n') : [],
            path: error.path
        })
    }));
```

On graphiql, when I attempt the following query:

```
{
  folderOne(filter: {}, sort: _ID_ASC) {
    name
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Expected [object Object] to be a GraphQL schema.",
      "stack": [
        "Error: Expected [object Object] to be a GraphQL schema.",
        "    at invariant (/Users/zied/work/share_place/node_modules/graphql/jsutils/invariant.js:19:11)",
        "    at validateSchema (/Users/zied/work/share_place/node_modules/graphql/type/validate.js:55:60)",
        "    at assertValidSchema (/Users/zied/work/share_place/node_modules/graphql/type/validate.js:80:16)",
        "    at validate (/Users/zied/work/share_place/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:58:35)",
        "    at /Users/zied/work/share_place/node_modules/express-graphql/dist/index.js:139:52",
        "    at <anonymous>",
        "    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What could I be missing???

p.s: sorry I attempted to tag the question with graphql-compose-mongoose but the tag doesn't exist, so I tagged it with graphql-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the issue was here:

```
const GraphQLSchema = require('./app_api/routes/graphql')
```

has to be replaced with

```
const GraphQLSchema = require('./app_api/routes/graphql').default
```

since we exported it as default

More info can be found here: https://github.com/graphql-compose/graphql-compose-mongoose/issues/103